# How can I configure MarkLogic to send a PUT request during initiating a backup and pointing to S3 compatible Object storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm executing a curl POST request:

```
curl --anyauth --user xyz:xyz123 -i -X POST -d'{"operation": "backup-database","forest": ["a","a-r1","b-cg2","b-r1","c","c-r1"],"backup-dir": "s3://abc-marklogic/MLbackup","incremental": false,"journal-archiving": true,"journal-archive-path": "/MLbackup/rest/","include-replicas": "true","lag-limit": 30}' -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost.uhc.com:8002/manage/v2/databases/{db-name}
```

Access to the Object storage Account is via S3 Compatible REST API. But it is sending GET request by default.

Here is the error that I'm getting:

> {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"400", "status":"Bad Request", "messageCode":"MANAGE-OPERATION", "message":"MANAGE-OPERATION: (err:FOER0000) Error performing operation: S3 socket error: GET https://zyz.abc.mno.com/ SVC-SOCCONN: Socket connect error: SSL_connect 10.86.52.125:56290-10.205.77.176:443: certificate verify failed

Answer (score 1):

This particular error is exactly what it says. Your 'S3 compatible' object store is failing certificate validation.
ML will use PUT to write the files but appears to be using GET to get a directory listing, which is what it would do if it was a local filesystem.

Recommend considering backing up to local FS then copying to your object store via whatever tool you have  that cant talk to it.

Comment: I resolved the certificate issue but turns out MarkLogic doesn't support non Amazon S3